Help understanding a step of the proof on the existence of a left invariant pseudometric on a topological group
The following theorem can be found in Hewitt-Ross Abstract Harmonic Analysis I, in chapter II
Theorem 8.2: Let $(U_k)_{k=1}^{\infty}$ be a sequence of symmetrics neighborhoods of $e\in G$ such that $ U_{k+1}^2 \subset U_k$, for $k = 1,2, \cdots$
Let $H = \bigcap_{k = 1}^{\infty} U_k$. Then there is a left invariant $\sigma$ on $G$ such that:
(i) $\sigma$ is uniformly continuous for the left uniform structure of $G\times G$
(ii) $\sigma(x,y) = 0 \iff y^{-1}x \in H$
(iii) $\sigma(x,y) \leq 2^{-k+2}$ whenever $y^{-1}x \in U_k$
(iv) $2^{-k} \leq \sigma(x,y)$ whenever $y^{-1}x \notin U_k$
My doubt is in the following step written in the book: By convenience, let's set $V_{2^{-k}} = U_k$, for $k = 1,2, \cdots$, and now define $V_r$ for all dyadic rational numbers $r, 0 < r < 1$ as follows
For $r = 2^{-l_1} + \cdots + 2^{-l_n}, 0 < l_1 < l_2 <  \cdots < l_n$ let
$V_r = V_{2^{-l_1}}V_{2^{-l_2}}\cdots V_{2^{-l_n}}$.
I want to show that if $r,s$ are dyadic rational numbers such that $0 < r < s < 1$, we have $V_r \subset V_s$. I'm confused about the sequence of inclusions in the book, I'm gonna write down exactly how is done there
Let $r = 2^{-l_1} + \cdots + 2^{-l_n}, 0 < l_1 < l_2 <  \cdots < l_n$
$s = 2^{-m_1} + \cdots + 2^{-m_p}, 0 < m_1 < m_2 <  \cdots < m_p$
There is a unique integer $k$ such that $l_j = m_j$ for $j < k$ and $l_k > m_k$
Letting $W = V_{2^{-l_1}}\cdots V_{2^{-l_{k-1}}}$, we have
$V_r  = WV_{2^{-l_k}}V_{2^{-l_{k+1}}}V_{2^{-l_{k+2}}}\cdots V_{2^{-l_n}}$
$\subset WV_{2^{-l_k}}V_{2^{-l_k}-1}V_{2^{-l_k}-2}\cdots V_{2^{-l_n}+1}V_{2^{-l_n}}V_{2^{-l_n}}$
$\subset WV_{2^{-l_k}}V_{2^{-l_k}-1}V_{2^{-l_k}-2}\cdots V_{2^{-l_n}+1}V_{2^{-l_n}}V_{2^{-l_n}}$
$\subset WV_{2^{-l_k}}V_{2^{-l_k}-1}V_{2^{-l_k}-2}\cdots V_{2^{-l_1}} V_{2^{-l_n}+1} V_{2^{-l_n}+1}\subset \cdots$
$\subset WV_{2^{-l_k}}V_{2^{-l_k}}\subset WV_{2^{-l_k}+1} \subset WV_{2^{-m_k}} = V_{2^{-l_1}}V_{2^{-l_2}}\cdots V_{2^{-l_{k-1}}}V_{2^{-m_k}}$
$\subset V_{2^{-m_1}}V_{2^{-m_2}}\cdots V_{2^{-m_{k-1}}}V_{2^{-m_k}}V_{2^{-m_{k+1}}}\cdots V_{2^{-m_p}}$
$ = V_s$
As you can see, sometimes the author writes a sum in the powers that are not in subindexes. For example, in the second line we have $V_{2^{-l_k}-1}$ instead of $V_{2^{-l_{k-1}}}$, and in the same line $V_{2^{-l_k}-2}$ instead of $V_{2^{-l_{k-2}}}$, etc. I can understand the logical steps from the second line and ahead, but the steps where the authors change the indexes from $l_{k-1}$ to $l_k-1$ is really confusing me, and it also took me a little bit time realizing that there was this subtle difference in the steps. If someone can clarify this to me I appreciate so much.
I also don't understand why $WV_{2^{-l_k}+1} \subset WV_{2^{-m_k}}$

The canonical answer.
The proof idea should be classical and simple but it seems that the long chain of inclusions with a lot of indices retracts from it. So I shall directly explain why $V_r\subset V_s$ instead.

There is a unique integer $k$ such that $l_j = m_j$ for $j < k$ and $l_k > m_k$"

Note that it also can happen that $k=n+1$, but then trivially $V_r\subset V_s$.
So we have $V_r =WU_{l_k}U_{l_{k+1}}\cdots U_{l_n}$. But for each natural $i$ we have
$U_{i+1}^2\subset U_i$. Then $$U_{i+1}U_{i+2}\subset U_{i+1}U_{i+1}\subset U_i,$$
$$U_{i+1}U_{i+2}U_{i+3}\subset U_{i+1}U_{i+2}U_{i+2}\subset U_{i+1}U_{i+1}\subset U_i,$$
and for any natural $j$ the product $U_{i+1}\dots U_{i+j}$ similarly collapses to a subset of $U_i$.
Since in the sequence $(l_k,l_{k+1},\dots,l_n)$ is increasing, we have $l_{k+j}\ge l_k+j$ for any natural $j\le n-k$, so
$$U_{l_k}U_{l_{k+1}}\cdots U_{l_n}\subset U_{l_k}U_{l_k+1}\cdots U_{l_k+n-k}\subset U_{l_k-1}
\subset U_{m_k}.$$ Thus
$$V_r =WU_{l_k}U_{l_{k+1}}\cdots U_{l_n}\subset WU_{m_k}\subset WU_{m_k}\dots U_{m_p}=V_s.$$
